Copying only cell color in Excel
I have a range of values with cells colored by a conditional formatting rule. I want to copy just the colors to another range of the same dimensions into which I can insert different values.

You can read DisplayFormat and use it as regular format, e.g.
Sub CopyDisplay()
    Dim cell As Range, clr As Long
    Range("C2:D5").Offset(, 5).ClearFormats
    For Each cell In Range("C2:D5")
        clr = cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
        If clr <> vbWhite Then _
            cell.Offset(, 5).Interior.Color = clr
    Next cell
End Sub


